# 0x800a138f - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

iam working using MVC and Entity framework , I have a view that displsy data of "BloodDonors" table from database and i can filter them by their blood group value that selected by dropdownlist ,so i want after choosing specific blood group i call the controller function that filters and pass them to the view for displaying.But after runing i get that exception:[0x800a138f - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected] beacause of JS code that i used in the view . Any help to handle that exception?
this is the JS code that i use to call controller function in the view :

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.16.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    debugger;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#DONOR_BLOOD_GROUPE_ID").change(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("FilterdIndex", "DONOR")',
                dataType: 'html',
                data: { id: $("#DONOR_BLOOD_GROUPE_ID").val() },
                success: function (data) {            
                },
                error: function (ex) {
                    alert('Failed to retrieve' + ex);
                    }
            });
           return false;
       })
   });
    </script>
```

the dropdownllist that call onchange func:

```
@Html.DropDownList("DONOR_BLOOD_GROUPE_ID","--Select--")
```

and this is the controller function that i call using JS code:

```
public ViewResult FilterdIndex(int id)
        {
          ViewBag.DONOR_BLOOD_GROUPE_ID = new SelectList(db.BLOOD_GROUP, "GROUP_ID", "GROUP_NAME");

            return View(db.DONOR.Where(u => u.DONOR_ID == id));
        }
```

Comment: There is no `AutoPostBack` feature in MVC, that's probably why it's failing.

Comment: You are including jQuery twice. That's not necessary, remove the unminified version.

Comment: @markpsmith ,so how can i solve it ? i don't have any ideas for doing that

Comment: @ZippyV , I removed it .but this doesn't  affect

Comment: Your code is not complete. Where is the function `FilterdIndex(...)`?

Comment: @ZippyV , i edited the definition of the dropdownlist but now it doesn't execute the  function in the controller :FilterdIndex , but in the previous definition it was executing it